# Sculpt tool not working

Tags: modeling, sculpting

Ok so I have pillaged google and forums all over and still I am at a loss. I have this blender file and any attempts to use the sculpt tool and it does not effect the object.
I have gone in checked for any subsurface modifiers, I have checked to make sure that I go from object mode - to edit mode - and finally to sculpt mode. I have checked all through the settings for any other applied modifiers. Along with checking to make sure it was not with the user preferences in blender as well.
Here is a link to the file [BLENDER FILE DOWNLOAD](https://expirebox.com/download/28e0e747ca17639626c77832e172c082.html) . You will be able to see that the sculpt tool is not working.
Any suggestions or information on what the problem could be would be most appreciated.
Thanks in adavance!

Comment: Sculpt Mode, Properties Panel, Active Tool and Workspace settings, Cursor <- Check

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally figured my no-sculpt problem, it was I was on a shape key with a value of 0. So check under Editor Type>Properties>Data>Shape Keys and make sure you're on "Basis" key, there are no keys, or a key with max value if relative is checked.
 I don't know about the specific problem but for the general one I thought I should add this solution.

Comment: Can you provide an image for this fix? I'm also a newbie to Blender and I don't know much about the interface,yet.

Answer (score 4):

This was something new. It seems that **Sculpt Tool** won't work if the **Clip End** is set to "inf". So for you to work with this mesh you can:

Set **Clip End** to **9999** or...

In **Object Mode**, mesh selected.

1. Reset location to center. Type 0,0,0 or press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > **Cursor to Center** than again this key combination and **Selection to Cursor**.
2. Scale it down. Much. <kbd>S</kbd> > 0.001 or just type **Dimensions**.
3. Apply scale. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > **Scale**.
4. Set **Clip** > **End** to something high but not "inf.
5. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Home</kbd> to center view to the scene.

[image: final]

Comment: @TheGugaru out of curiosity, how to enter "inf" value? I've seen it for the first time. Never mind, I've just hold 9 button for a while and it set it to "inf" automatically.

Comment: you can also just type inf ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, but it's because I used the smooth modifier and didn't apply it before using sculpt brush.